# Build errors when used Switch case when statement?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I am using a switch case when statement and builds are throwing errors. What is wrong with my code?

```
switch (lstCusRelationship.Count)
{
    case int n when (n >= 1 && n < 5): 
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward = 5 - lstCusRelationship.Count;
        break;
    case int n when (n >= 5 && n < 10): 
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward = 10 - lstCusRelationship.Count;
        break;
    case int n when (n >= 10 && n < 25): 
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward = 25 - lstCusRelationship.Count;
        break;
    case int n when (n >= 25 && n < 50): 
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward = 50 - lstCusRelationship.Count;
        break;
    case int n when (n >= 50 && n < 75): 
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward = 75 - lstCusRelationship.Count;
        break;
    case int n when (n >= 75 && n < 100):
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward = 100 - lstCusRelationship.Count;
        break;
    case int n when (n >= 100): 
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward =  lstCusRelationship.Count;
        break;
}
```

errors

```
MemberReferral.cs(35,30): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'int' 
MemberReferral.cs(35,37): error CS1528: Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration)
MemberReferral.cs(35,54): error CS1002: ; expected 
MemberReferral.cs(35,54): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ':'
```

Comment: is this version issue? becaue its working in my local but I am trying build on server to deploy causing this issue.

Comment: language version 9

Comment: Well, the older versions don't understand new syntax, so it's a possibility. Can't you just build it where you wrote it and then deploy the binaries to the server?

Comment: whats older syntax?

Comment: pattern matching using `when` wasn't introduced until c# 7, so anything older than that.

Comment: Can you share me with the older syntax for the Switch case range check? Now upgrade server is heck approval need. I was looking all over the place not found the correct one.

Comment: The older syntax for range checking is to use `if` statements

Comment: What is c# vesrion?

Comment: Have you tried to test this code in a simple console app(works for me in net 5 and net framework)? One of your errors says that there is a constructor. Check if everything good with all other codes.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to try using older syntax if you're on a machine with an older .NET Framework/C# version:

```cs
    if (lstCusRelationship.Count < 1)
    {
        // do nothing?
    }
    else if (lstCusRelationship.Count < 5)
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward = 5 - lstCusRelationship.Count;
    else if (lstCusRelationship.Count < 10)
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward = 10 - lstCusRelationship.Count;
    else if (lstCusRelationship.Count < 25)
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward = 25 - lstCusRelationship.Count;
    else if (lstCusRelationship.Count < 50)
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward = 50 - lstCusRelationship.Count;
    else if (lstCusRelationship.Count < 75)
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward = 75 - lstCusRelationship.Count;
    else if (lstCusRelationship.Count < 100)
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward = 100 - lstCusRelationship.Count;
    else
        memberReferral.NumNeedForAward = lstCusRelationship.Count;
```